# How do I set up a new Drupal website user account and assign them a civi role?

Tags: user

I want to allow someone to view the backend of the website and Drupal but not make any changes.

Answer (score 2):

If you create a Drupal user, and if your CiviCRM integration is set up correctly, then a CiviCRM contact record will be created that is connected to that Drupal user.

If your CiviCRM Contact already exists then you can either

- click on Actions and create CMS User from there or
- create a Drupal user via Drupal and if it matches email then it should connect them.

Then there are then a LOT of civicrm permissions via the Drupal interface that you can set depending on what you want that person to do.